# how to install freeradius server?

Tags: debugging, openssl, freeradius, heartbleed-bug

could anyone have freeradius server installation guideliness/documentation?.

because i tried to install several times, it completes,but while running in debugging mode it caused so many problems/errors on 
openssl like

1.header missmached.

2.heartbleed error.

3.vulnerable

4.etc,..

.i think,i skipped some steps while installation on my server system,why means freeradius server compets me and doesn't works properly?.

if anyone would give guidlines or documentation, it would be helps me.!!!

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software installation/usage tech support.

Answer (score 1):

Header mismatch is a result of a different version being reported by the headers and the library. To fix that, pass `--with-openssl-lib-dir=DIR` and `--with-openssl-include-dir=DIR` to the configure script to set the path to the OpenSSL libraries and headers explicitly.

To fix the heartbleed error, install OpenSSL > 1.0.1g, and use the configure arguments above.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://freeradius.org/security.html

> v3.0.x - Administrators can over-ride this check by setting
>   **allow_vulnerable_openssl = CVE-2014-0160** in the **security** subsection of
>   **radiusd.conf**.